# Is there a way to make MVC.NET routing ignore a few /dir/paths/?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing

Meaning I could have the URL routing start at like site.com/v3/site/controller/action

basically it would ignore the v3/site/ and treat that as root?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You sure can. Check out the following routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("Route1", "StaticFolder/{name}/{id}", new { controller = "Controller1", action = "Action1", name = "Sample", id = "1" });
```

Route 1 will always invoke `Action1` on `Controller1` on any requests for resources in `StaticFolder`.

```
routes.MapRoute("Route2", "StaticFolder1/{id}/{action}", new { controller = "Controller2", action = "Action2", id = "1" });
```

Route 2 will always invoke `Controller2` with specified action (defaulting to `Action2`) for any requests to StaticFolder1.

In your case specifically though you want to remove the default route and replace it with the following:

```
routes.MapRoute("Default", "/v3/site/{controller}/{action}/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });
```

Comment: routes.MapRoute("Default", "/v4/shell/{controller}/{action}/{id}", New With {.controller = "Demo", .action = "Test", .id = ""}) DID NOT WORK...

Comment: What's the real root path within your application? Does the application have a virtual path (for example myhost.com/myapp/) or does it start at myhost.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the the application root is at /v3/site. As far as I know, ASP-MVC's routing can't intercept routes below its own root (would likely be a security issue). Seems more like an IIS configuration that's needed than an MVC routing rule.